# Select records where column has n character occurrences

Tags: sql, sqlite, count, substr

I was wondering if this is possible in sqlite.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE substr_count(f, '*') = 5
```

It should return records that have 5 asterisks in the "f" column, like

```
a*b**c**

****a*
```

and so on

Answer (score 2):

SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE length(f)-replace(f,'*','') = 5

Answer (score 1):

This solution is easy if you have a tally or numbers table which simply contains a sequential list of integers. This would be a table you populated once but has many uses. With that you have:

```
Create Table Tally ( N int );

Insert Tally( N )

...

Select Z.<PrimaryKeyCol>, Sum( Z.Val )
From    (
        Select <PrimaryKeyCol>, 1 As Val
        From tbl
            Cross Join Tally As T
        Where substr( tbl.f, T.N, 1 )  = '*'
        ) As Z
Group By Z.<PrimaryKeyCol>
Having Sum( Z.Val ) = 5
```